# React parent-component's state shouldn't rerender child component in all cases

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React app. There is a component **Main**, which is the parent-component.

**Main** has child-components:

- Date filtering
- Location filtering
- Different charts showing data based on filters

**Main** is the one keeping track of the filters using state. So when the filters are updated in the child-components, that's communicated to Main. Main updates because of that, including its child components.

-> Main updates
-> Child components (charts) actually rerender (constructor is called)

The problem: one of the charts, which is quite heavy to load because of the many requests, reloads/rerenders when either of the filters is changed, even though it only uses 1 of the filters.
So when Location Filtering is updated, it's correct that the carts reloads. When Date Filtering is updated, the chart shouldn't reload. State is communicated to the chart through requestParams().

See code snippets below:

Main.js

```
class Main extends React.Component {

requestParams(comparison = false)
{
let storeFilters     = this.state.selectedStoreFilters;
let territoryFilters = this.state.selectedTerritoryFilters;
let countryFilters   = this.state.selectedCountryFilters;

let dateFilter   = this.state.selectedDateFilter;
let dateRange    = this.state.selectedDateRange;
let surveyFilter = this.state.selectedSurveyFilter;
let otherFilters = this.state.selectedOtherFilters;

var params = {};

/**
 * In some cases the params passed into the component is twice the same, which
 * prevents the component from reloading new data (because there is no change).
 *
 * Adding the timestamp makes us able to detect new params -> request new data.
 */
params.paramsCreatedTimestamp = Date.now();

// In the case of non-continuous surveys, there might be situations where there are no
// comparison surveys. In that case the are no apiParams, because no data is needed.
if (!this.props.props.isContinuous && comparison && surveyFilter.comparison == null)
{
  return null;
}


// Set date range.
if (this.props.props.isContinuous && dateRange != null)
{
  if (comparison)
  {
    let comparisonDateRange = DateHelper.comparisonDateRange(dateRange);
    params.from = DateHelper.formattedDateTime(comparisonDateRange.startDate, false);
    params.to   = DateHelper.formattedDateTime(comparisonDateRange.endDate, true);
  }
  else
  {
    params.from = DateHelper.formattedDateTime(dateRange.startDate, false);
    params.to   = DateHelper.formattedDateTime(dateRange.endDate, true);
  }
}
else if (this.props.props.isContinuous && dateFilter != null)
{
  let dates   = comparison
    ? DateHelper.comparisonDateLimits(dateFilter, null, this.props.i18n.language)
    : DateHelper.dateLimits(dateFilter, null, this.props.i18n.language);
  params.from = dates.from;
  params.to   = dates.to;
}
else
{
  let dates = comparison
    ? surveyFilter.comparison
    : surveyFilter.current;
  params.from = DateHelper.formattedDateTime(dates.from, false);
  params.to   = DateHelper.formattedDateTime(dates.to, true);
}


// Set survey filter
if (this.props.props.isContinuous)
{
  params.survey_ids = [this.props.props.survey.id];
}
else
{
  params.survey_ids = comparison
    ? surveyFilter.comparison.surveys.map(survey => survey.id)
    : surveyFilter.current.surveys.map(survey => survey.id);
}


// Set store filter.
if (storeFilters != null && Array.isArray(storeFilters) && ArrayHelper.hasOtherThanNull(storeFilters))
{
  if (storeFilters[0] === -1)
  {
    params.store_ids = this.props.props.areas.stores.map(s => s.id);
  }
  else
  {
    params.store_ids = storeFilters;
  }
}

// Set territory filter.
if (territoryFilters != null && Array.isArray(territoryFilters) && ArrayHelper.hasOtherThanNull(territoryFilters))
{
  if (territoryFilters[0] === -1)
  {
    params.territory_ids = this.props.props.areas.territories.map(t => t.id);
  }
  else
  {
    params.territory_ids = territoryFilters;
  }
}

// Set country filter.
if (countryFilters != null && Array.isArray(countryFilters) && ArrayHelper.hasOtherThanNull(countryFilters))
{
  if (countryFilters[0] === -1)
  {
    params.country_ids = this.props.props.areas.countries.map(c => c.id);
  }
  else
  {
    params.country_ids = countryFilters;
  }
}


// Set other filters.
params.filters = {};

let allBackgroundFilters = otherFilters.filter(f => f instanceof BackgroundFilter);
let allQuestionFilters   = otherFilters.filter(f => f instanceof QuestionFilter);

allBackgroundFilters.map(backgroundFilter => {
  params.filters[backgroundFilter.criterion.identifier] = backgroundFilter.getTrimmedQuery()
});

params.filters.question_filters = [];
allQuestionFilters.map(questionFilter => {
  params.filters.question_filters.push({
    question_id: questionFilter.getId(),
    option_ids:  questionFilter.getFilteredOptions().map(o => o.id),
  })
});

params.locale = this.props.i18n.language;

return params;
}

  /**
   * All props for the chart components.
   */
  chartPropsCollection()
  {
    return {
      colorScales:   this.props.props.colorScales,
      mainCriteria:  this.props.props.mainCriteria,
      otherCriteria: this.props.props.otherCriteria,
      npsCriteria:   this.props.props.npsCriteria,

      npsAsScore: this.props.props.npsAsScore,

      apiParams:           this.requestParams(),
      comparisonApiParams: this.requestParams(true),

      dateString:           this.dateString(),
      comparisonDateString: this.dateString(true),

      isContinuous: this.props.props.isContinuous,
      surveys:      this.state.surveys,
      scale:        this.props.props.scale,
      decimals:     this.props.props?.scale?.show_decimals == true ? 1 : 0,

      showVisitDate:  this.props.props.showVisitDate,
      showExternalId: this.props.props.showExternalId,

      showKeywords:      this.props.props.showKeywords,
      showSiblingScores: this.props.props.showSiblingScores,

      storeFilters:     this.state.selectedStoreFilters,
      territoryFilters: this.state.selectedTerritoryFilters,
      countryFilters:   this.state.selectedCountryFilters,
    };
  }

  render () {
    return (
    <ContinuousScoreTrend {..._this.chartPropsCollection()} />
    );
  }
```

How would I go about **not** reloading the chart is certain states of Main (and in requestParams) are updated, only for other?

Comment: Wrap `ContinuousScoreTrend` in a [`React.memo`](https://react.dev/reference/react/memo) with a custom `arePropsEqual` that will block rerenders when date filtering changes.

Comment: But does that work, as Main already seems to rerender itself completely with State changes (but constructor is not called)

Comment: Or should I add `arePropsEqual` to Main as well, and prevent rerenders in (almost) all cases? In the end Main is mostly a wrapper for all child-components. It does keep track of the states, but in the end it's the child-components using them.
Main uses the 'tab' -state. When a different tab is selected, different child-components are shown

Comment: No you would wrap `ContinuousScoreTrend`. That is the component that is expensive to render, not the parent. If `ContinuousScoreTrend` is memoized, rerenders in Main will not necessarily mean rerenders in `ContinuousScoreTrend`.